# Path derivative

Tags: derivatives, vectors

Let $\vec y$ be a vector that represents the path of a particle through space. If we define $w$ as the length of the path, would it be correct to say that $\displaystyle \frac{d\vec y}{dw}$ evaluated at any point on the curve is equal to the unit vector tangent to the path at that point?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right.  If we parametrize the curve with respect to some parameter $t$, then $\frac{d\vec y}{dt}$ at any given point is a vector that is tangent to the curve at any given point, so $\frac{\frac{d\vec y}{dt}}{\|\frac{d\vec y}{dt}\|}$ is the unit tangent vector.  But in the case when we're parametrizing the curve with respect to the arc length $w$, the unit tangent vector is just $\frac{d\vec y}{dw}$, because $\|\frac{d\vec y}{dw}\|=1$.  (Try proving that.)

EDIT: I should mention that the usual notation used is $\vec r$ and $s$ instead of $\vec y$ and $w$.